# Auth Issue in Firebase Real Time Database Rest API with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I was working fine with Firebase Real Time Database in developer environment and my flutter app, with read and write rule in true, but now, firebase force me to change the privileges, I have now this:

[image: firebase code permissions]

```
  "rules": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null"
```

}

My code is this:

```
Future<List<Dispositiu>> cargarDispositivos() async {
final url = '$_url/dispositius.json?auth=${_prefs.token}';
print('$_url/dispositius.json?auth=${_prefs.token}');

final resp = await http.get(url);

final Map<String, dynamic> decodeData = json.decode(resp.body);

final List<Dispositiu> dispositivosList = new List();

if (decodeData == null) return [];

decodeData.forEach((id, dispositius) {
  final dispTemp = Dispositiu.fromJson(dispositius);
  dispTemp.id = id;

  dispositivosList.add(dispTemp);
});
```

And If I see my log, I can see the url that I'm passing to it with the correct UID and the erro:

I/flutter ( 1608): https://X-dee33.firebaseio.com/dispositius.json?auth=gcKXXXXjrd2H1KFmi4sFbO52

I/flutter ( 1608): Could not parse auth token.

I have in the Firebase the email/password auth enable and I have been able to work well in the past with the old permissions

But now I can't connect with the Firebase, I attach an image[image: Error Flutter].

Any Idea???

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  If you have an error, copy that message into the question and point out which line it's on.

Comment: Ok Stevenson, sorry, I paste the code and put the image too, any idea about this issue???

Comment: You can replace both images with texy it by editing the question using the edit link at the bottom and copying the code in their place.

Comment: I put the firts image in code to... but there are 3 lines of code... and the second image I already had the code and the image